# Shall I use package name or class name to reprensent a concept?

Tags: java, class, package, naming-conventions

I have been debating the naming for java packages and java class name.

The problem I ran into is as follows: we have an interface called Feature, and we have child interfaces such as: LogInFeature and AuthenticationFeature. Both of the interfaces have their specific API(s), and they are both inside the same package For this problem, which package/class naming structure is more favorable and why?

```
com.example.internal.feature.LogIn
com.example.internal.feature.Authentication
```

vs

```
com.example.internal.features.LogInFeature
com.example.internal.features.AuthenticationFeature
```

I like the 1st solution because it doesn't duplicate Feature in all the classes. But on the flip side, I also like the 2nd solution because appending Feature at the end helps code discovery a lot in a big code base.

If besides internal features, I also have external features, or if I allow our customers to add feature plugins, will the answer be different?

Any comment and suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: I would prefer the 1st solution. with that you code looks elegant and you end up with all the interfaces in your module at the same place. you might want to create packages based on the module and not based on the particular functionality as this makes your code break into patches which you don't want to i guess.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but where would you put `Feature` interface if you were to go with the first solution? (Just out of curiosity... :$)

Comment: @wns349, the code itself didn't carry a lot of thought in the past. Feature.java is currently inside the same package: com.example.internal.feature.

Comment: @wns349 well i would suggest put the Feature and child interfaces in the same feature package. I would go with it as all of your child interfaces would land at the same level as parent interface.

Comment: @vikeng21, will the answer be different if I have other packages like com.example.external.feature/features?

Comment: @Lily in that case you can put all the parent features in a package and dependent child features in another package so that atleast you can differentiate between the two. btw i would go more for code clarity and avoid creating tons of packages in my code. hope you got the point choose the best possible soln after all you are the developer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to go for the second variant, with the slightly longer class names.

The reasoning behind this is that I feel that I should be able to tell what the class is responsible for just by looking at the name. Also, it is less confusing (to me at least) in case the code later also contains something related to `LogIn` in another package, which would lead to two classes with the same name.

Comment: Do you think the naming: LogIn and Authentication are bad?

Comment: @Lily: Not really, but I think the longer names are much better.